# javascript random item in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

So I have an array of `strings: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]`, but I want `array[4]` to be a random string each time it is used, so:

```
array[0] returns "a",
array[1] returns "b",

array[4] returns something random, like "x",
array[4] returns something random the second time as well, like "y",
```

There is a function random(), but if I set `array[4]` equal to random() it will hold on to that random value, but it needs to stay random every time it is called.

Comment: Instead of calling `array[4]` - just call `random()`?

Comment: This seems like something better suited for javascript object/class using getters and setters

Comment: No I want to call array[4] not random, I know it's a bit vague

Comment: +1 to this question that made me learn something I could not think was possible!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

```
var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
Object.defineProperty(a, 4, { get: Math.random });

console.log(a[4]); // some random number
console.log(a[4]); // another random number
```

Comment: nice! Didn't know that!

Comment: @FrancescoMM the nice thing about `Object.defineProperty` is it doesn't require any special syntax and it works after the object is instantiated. If you don't mind special-purpose syntax and can get away with setting up the accessor during instantiation, your solution works too (+1 to you).

Comment: ..but mine is not even an array.. :(

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = { get 4() {return getRandomInt(1,10);} }

alert(array[4]);
alert(array[4]);
alert(array[4]);



function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    function random() {
        character = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor( Math.random() * 26) + "a".charCodeAt(0));
        return character;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you could accomplish similar functionality

```
arrayManager = {
    array: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
    set: function(i, v) {
        this.array[i] = v;
    }
    get: function(i) {
        if (i == 4) return random();
        else return this.array[i];
    }
};

var random = arrayManager.get(4);
```